# TCP port without network adapter

Tags: sockets, tcp, ethernet, communication-protocol

I am intending to write some software modules that will all run on a single machine, and I would like for them to communicate with each other via TCP.

It is likely that the machine I am using will not have a physical network adapter. Will TCP connections to localhost be able to work correctly if there is no physical network adapter?

The operating system that I am running on is Linux for Tegra.

Thanks.

Comment: Of course. Keyword is "localhost loopback adapter".

Comment: You do not need a physical network adapter, but you do need a TCP software stack installed. I am not familiar with Linux for Tegra, so I do not know if it includes it.

Comment: I know it's not `tcp`, but you can try to ping yourself: `ping -c 4 127.0.0.1`